# dataframe merge on left adding extra rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I create a invoice dataframe and a number of master dataframes from  csv files

```
invoice=pd.read_csv('rocaInv4.csv')

soMstr=pd.read_csv('salesOfficeMstr.csv')
custFreightMstr=pd.read_csv('customerCodeFreightMstr.csv')
ratesMstr=pd.read_csv('freightMstr.csv')
pfep=pd.read_csv('pfepMstr.csv')
```

I drop a number of rows depending on availability in material masters and customer masters.  I reindex each time.

```
#checking availability of material
invoice=invoice[invoice['Material'].isin(pfep['Material'])]
invoice=invoice.reset_index(drop=True)

#checking availability of customer details
invoice=invoice[invoice['Ship to Party'].isin(custFreightMstr['Cust No'])]
invoice=invoice.reset_index(drop=True)

#checking validity of sales code
invoice=invoice[invoice['Sales Office'].isin(soMstr['Code'])]
invoice=invoice.reset_index(drop=True)

invoice.shape
#(384, 22)
```

I then need to copy data from the masters to the final, clean Invoice DataFrame.  Instead of doing a for loop over two data frames, I thought I would do a merge on select columns.

```
invoice1=invoice.merge(custFreightMstr[['Cust No','City','Customer Frgt Code']],left_on='Ship to Party',right_on='Cust No', how='left').drop_duplicates()

invoice1.shape
#(388, 25)
```

I end up with 4 extra rows even though I am merging on the left.  I can identify which rows have been repeated.  But I cant identify why.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For one `Ship to Party` you might be having more than one `Cust No` on the left, due to which you might be getting more rows.  Can't say much without seeing the data but how many unique pairs of `(Ship to Party, Cust No)` are there in final dataframe?

Comment: Ah!  I assumed the master was clean.  I checked and found 4 repeated, exactly same as increased rows.  Thanks a lot!  Is there anyway to specify just use the first match in a merge?  All this is sample data, I have no control over how clean it can be

Comment: You can drop the rows based on duplicates values of the key before merging. Use 'drop_duplicates` with `subset` parameter. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The merge in your code is equivalent to `left outer join`. As discussed you have more than one matching keys `Cust No` for a value of `Ship to Party`. Remove the duplicate keys in the master dataframe. That might help.

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue which of the repeated `Cust No` in the master frame is correct.  For coding purposes, I executed the following:

```
#drop duplicate cust no in the master
invoice1=invoice.merge(custFreightMstr.drop_duplicates('Cust No',keep='last')[['Cust No','City','Customer Frgt Code']],left_on='Ship to Party',right_on='Cust No', how='left',validate = 'm:1')
```

drop_duplicate on 'Cust No'removes all duplicates, retaining the last entry alone.

The validate keyword confirms there is only one of each cust code during  actual merge.